# How to define class variables, which I could use in all class methods

Tags: typescript

I got the next problem: I have to define the variables which I could use in class methods. Like this:

```
class MyClass {
   let var1;
   let var2;

   method1() {
      var1 = var2;
   }
   method2() {
      var1 = "something";
      var2 = 32;
   }
}
```

I tried to use class properties, but it does not work for me. I believe that  exists a way how define such variables in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

> Just remove the `let`, `var` or `const` from the variable.
>   And reference them using `this` keyword.

```js
class MyClass {
   var1: string | number;
   var2: number;

   method1() {
      this.var1 = this.var2;
   }
   method2() {
      this.var1 = "something";
      this.var2 = 32;
   }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20var1%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20var2%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20method1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.var1%20%3D%20this.var2%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20method2()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.var1%20%3D%20%22something%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.var2%20%3D%2032%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)